# Android Studio doesn't create new project

Tags: android, android-studio, new-project

I'm using the newest version of Android Studio on Windows 7. I'm trying to create new project with blank activity. It creates project folder with some system-required files but there's no manifest, activity or layout file (remember, I asked it to create blank activity), even no src directory. What's the solution of this problem? It seems that I'm not the only person who faced it.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, accidentally I found the solution: I used some non-latin symbols in my workspace-path. When I changed it to only-latin - the project creates correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a new project, you have to select **"Android Application Project"** (File --> New--> Android Application Project) instead of directly creating **Android Activity**. Once you have created a new "Android Application Project", you will find all the required files & then you can go on creating "Blank Activities" (File --> New --> Others--> Android --> Android Activity --> Blank Activity).

Comment: @user1049280: Oops! I think I might have trivialized your problem before you uploaded this screenshot.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) I'm sure that I'm trying to create project, not activity. However I've alreday found the solution, check it in my answer :)